# VueJS - How to apply directives to all matching tags?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue.js, vue-directives

I'd like to apply a directive to all `input` tags programmatically. Two reasons for this are:

1. I don't want to have to go through all inputs in my app to add the directive
2. If I want to change the directive against all inputs at a later date, it's in one place.

Is this possible? I've reviewed the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html) but they don't seem to mention applying it in any other way than applying the tag directly to the element.

My current code is like so:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="price" v-model="model.doc.price" v-floating-label>
```

Comment: Do you want to conditionally add that directive?

Comment: @DivyanthJayaraj Not as it stands but I can see potential for that requirement going forward, so if it's possible, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having a brain dead moment it seems. I just need an `input` **component**. I can then change what I need on there and it will update everywhere the input component has been used and instead of using the standard html `input` tag, I'll use my component.

Long day ...

I've answered this question myself instead of deleting it in case anybody else has the same brain dead moment in the future ;)

Comment: You made my day!

Answer (score 1):

As per Evan You:

> Vue.js compilation happens when you instantiate/mount the root instance.

See https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/77#issuecomment-60339440

I don't think what your are trying to do is sane: search and replace, coming out of the box in many text editors or IDE, will be really helpful for your two explained reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind that directive to a condition like so

```
<input type="text" 
       class="form-control input-sm" 
       id="price" 
       v-model="model.doc.price" 
       :v-floating-label=(condition)>
```

If `condition == true` , `v-model-float` directive will be applied to your input.

**Update 1**: From the comments, the implementation will still be the same, except you control the condition from one place. That way, you can remove the directive at a later date by simply setting that condition to false.

Comment: I know how to apply a directive to an input (my original code shows that). I want to apply it to *ALL* inputs programatically. P.s I've edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: So you want your vue app to parse through the DOM, find input tags and apply that directive?

Comment: Essentially, yes.

Comment: So is it not the case that you want to automatically add that directive every time you have an input tag in your template while writing the code?

Comment: I don't want the code to have the directive (as this means I need to change every input if I ever want to remove it). I'd like it to apply to all inputs automatically.

Comment: @webnoob Is Vue building your HTML? If not, why not? That's the whole point of it.

Comment: @Tomalak Yeah, you're right. I was having a bad moment it seems :) Head was stuck on one thing and wouldn't let go ... sigh.